Spring Boot 3.3.2: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter2
I have upgraded the Spring Boot version from 3.2.2 to 3.3.2.
While running the application, I am facing this error given below :
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter2
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 20 more

I have these logback dependencies added in the pom.xml given below:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.14</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

I have checked in the project and there are no dependency conflicts.
How to resolve this issue?

Spring Boot automatically includes logback. Remove the dependencies and you will get the proper version (no need to add spring-boot-starter-logging for this).

Spring Boot 3.3.2 uses logback version 1.5.6.
So, you need to upgrade your logback library from 1.4.14 to 1.5.6.
FYI: The logback-core version 1.5.6 has the ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter2 class in it.
Just update the existing logback dependencies given below in the pom.xml:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Also, you don't need to add these dependencies explicitly for logback as Spring Boot comes with logback libraries by default. So, you can safely remove these dependencies.
Read the Java docs on ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter2 for more information.
See if this helps.

When using Spring Boot, you shouldn't explicitly specify versions of dependencies that are used by Spring Boot. You should allow Spring Boot to manage the versions for you.

Yes, but even if you do specify the dependencies explicitly, you don't need to (nor should you) specify the versions if they are dependencies managed by Spring Boot.

With this 1.5.6  version it worked for me.

I removed the version for all logback dependencies and it worked fine for me.
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

