Spring boot 3.3.2, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/util/StatusPrinter2
I've just updated my Spring Boot application to version 3.3.2 lts. But when I try to run it, I get the following stack error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/util/StatusPrinter2
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:110)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem$Factory.getLoggingSystem(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:495)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.DelegatingLoggingSystemFactory.getLoggingSystem(DelegatingLoggingSystemFactory.java:44)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem.get(LoggingSystem.java:167)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:237)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:220)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:156)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$starting$0(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)
at com.alpha.ct.CompensationToolApplication.main(CompensationToolApplication.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter2
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
... 20 more
Someone can help me please, thanks in advance.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/78858224/2436237

This question is similar to: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter2 for Spring Boot 3.3.2. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have already answered this. Please have a look.

Hi @AnishB. I've already tried this solution, but it doesn't work for me.
And on the other hand, I want to understand why it is necessary to define these deps knowing that spring-boot-start-logging already defines them.
Thanks in advance.
